# Change the comment character (%) for the doc class

Tags: comments, documentation, catcodes, dtx, doc

When generating files from a `*.dtx` source, Docstrip discards lines starting with the comment character `%` (unless they contain guards `%<guard>content`). When typesetting the documentation with utilities like the `doc` package, the same file is usually included using `\DocInput{file.dtx}`, which then causes the formerly left out material to be typeset, including the uncommented code between `\begin{macrocode}` and `\end{macrocode}`.

I wonder whether it would be possible to process the comment syntax of other languages with Docstrip. E.g. for python, `%` would have to be switched out with `#`. Other languages utilize multiple characters to start comment lines, for example `//` in C. If the character `doc` looks for could be changed, source files could be typeset while still remaining valid and readily executable in their original language.

Is it possible to change the `%` sign to one or multiple other characters with regards to what `\DocInput` does?

Comment: Note that you can use DocStrip with other languages: would be my usual approach

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe `doc` can be so customized without producing your own version that looked for other characters. For example, the `\xmacro@code` macro in `doc` is defined to look explicitly for `%    \end{macrocode}`.

```
\catcode`\!=\catcode`\%   ^^A In this section there must not be
                              ^^A any exclamation marks.
                              ^^A
\begingroup
\catcode`\|=\z@ \catcode`\[=\@ne \catcode`\]=\tw@
\catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12
\catcode`\%=12 \catcode`\ =\active \catcode`\\=\active
!%    \end{macrocode*}
!    Next follows the actual definition of  |\macro@code|;
!    notice the
!    use of the new escape character.  We manage to get the argument
!    surrounded by the string |\end{macrocode}|, but at the end
!    however, in spite of the actual characters used during the
!    definition of
!    this macro, |\end| with the argument |{macrocode}|
!    will be executed, to ensure a balanced environment.
!    \begin{macrocode*}
|gdef|xmacro@code#1%    \end{macrocode}[#1|end[macrocode]]
!%    \end{macrocode*}
```

This code is a little confusing but the key parts are that `!` is a comment, `|` is a `\`, `[` is `{`, and `]` is `}`. `{`, `}`, and `%` are normal symbols and `\` and space are made active. So the line

```
|gdef|xmacro@code#1%    \end{macrocode}[#1|end[macrocode]]
```

is essentially

```
\gdef\xmacro@code#1%    \end{macrocode}{#1\end{macrocode}}
```

except that the `%` and the four spaces are required to be there.

Presumably, you could modify `doc.sty` to handle something like `#` instead, but it seems like a lot of work.

This is purely a matter of opinion, but I find literate programs extremely hard to read. Reading a `.dtx` file is much harder for me than reading a `.sty` file with some comments. Similarly, I find [tex.web](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/dist/tex/tex.web) to be very hard to read. A better option might be to use tools specifically designed for the other languages rather than trying to coerce `doc` to fit your use case.

Comment: Regarding the comment in your last paragraph: I think in literate programming, the "source" files like `tex.web` are not meant to be read by humans. I'm pretty sure even Knuth thinks of the typeset TeX program (as in Volume B) as the "real" version, and `tex.web` is merely a way of producing both it and a complied version, which he would open only briefly after looking at the program on paper and knowing exactly what change to make. After all, he wrote the entire TeX program with pencil on paper.